# Generate a list of dictonary elements for files in folder

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I am making a script that lists the existing files in a directory,and then save them to a dictionary list. In the directory there are two types of images, "foo" and "bar", which at the end of the name have an identifier to know the position in which they should be viewed, for example:

```
foo_1.jpg
foo_2.jpg
foo_5.jpg
bar_1.jpg
bar_2.jpg
bar_3.jpg
```

And I want to get the next result:

```
files = [ {'position': 1, 'foo': '/img/foo_1.jpg','bar': '/img/bar_1.jpg'},
          {'position': 2, 'foo': '/img/foo_2.jpg','bar': '/img/bar_2.jpg'},
          {'position': 3, 'foo': '','bar': '/img/bar_3.jpg',
          {'position': 5, 'foo': '/img/foo_5.jpg','bar': ''} ]
```

There's my code:

```
def files_in_folder(folder_name):
    folder_path = os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],   'files', str(folder_name))
    data = []
    if not os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        return [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
    else:
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
            position = int(re.search('[0-9]+', filename).group())
            if "foo" in filename:
                foo_register = {'position': position,
                                'foo': folder_path + '/' + filename, 
                                'bar': ''}
            else:
                bar_register = {'position': position,
                                'foo': '', 
                                'bar': folder_path + '/' + filename }
            register = {**foo_register, **bar_register}
            data.insert(position-1, register)
            print(data)
```

My result is:

```
[{'foo': '', 'bar': 'uploads/campaigns/1/bar_1.png', 'position': 1},
 {'foo': '', 'bar': 'uploads/campaigns/1/bar_2.png', 'position': 2},
 {'foo': '', 'bar': 'uploads/campaigns/1/bar_3.png', 'position': 3},
 {'foo': 'uploads/campaigns/1/foo_1.png', 'bar': '', 'position': 1,
 {'foo': '', 'bar': 'uploads/campaigns/1/bar_3.png', 'position': 3}]
```

What I'm missing in my code?. There's a best pythonic way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just realised that I didn't need to specify a key function for `sorted`. It won't hurt anything, it's just marginally less efficient. Please see my updated answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, I don't have those files on my HD, so here's some code that processes a list of file names, but it shouldn't be hard to adapt it for your purposes.

The heart of this code is a helper function `parse_name` that extracts the position (`pos`) and image type info (`kind`) from a file name.

To organize that info the way you want I put it into a dict of dicts. We then sort the keys of the outer dict to create the desired list of dicts. We use a numeric sort so that `11` doesn't sort before `2`, etc.

```
import os.path
from pprint import pprint

data = '''\
/img/foo_1.jpg
/img/foo_2.jpg
/img/foo_5.jpg
/img/bar_1.jpg
/img/bar_2.jpg
/img/bar_3.jpg
'''.splitlines()

def parse_name(s):
    fname = os.path.basename(s)
    fbase, _ = os.path.splitext(fname)
    kind, pos = fbase.split('_')
    return kind, int(pos)

files_dict = {} 
for s in data:
    kind, pos = parse_name(s)
    d = files_dict.setdefault(pos, {'position': pos})
    d[kind] = s

pprint(files_dict)
print()

files_list = [files_dict[k] for k in sorted(files_dict.keys(), key=int)]
pprint(files_list)
```

**output**

```
{1: {'bar': '/img/bar_1.jpg', 'foo': '/img/foo_1.jpg', 'position': 1},
 2: {'bar': '/img/bar_2.jpg', 'foo': '/img/foo_2.jpg', 'position': 2},
 3: {'bar': '/img/bar_3.jpg', 'position': 3},
 5: {'foo': '/img/foo_5.jpg', 'position': 5}}

[{'bar': '/img/bar_1.jpg', 'foo': '/img/foo_1.jpg', 'position': 1},
 {'bar': '/img/bar_2.jpg', 'foo': '/img/foo_2.jpg', 'position': 2},
 {'bar': '/img/bar_3.jpg', 'position': 3},
 {'foo': '/img/foo_5.jpg', 'position': 5}]
```

---

Actually, we don't need that sort key function, since `pos` has already been converted to `int` in `parse_name`. Oops! :) So we can just do:

```
files_list = [files_dict[k] for k in sorted(files_dict.keys())]
```

---

That `for` loop *could* be condensed to:

```
for s in data:
    kind, pos = parse_name(s)
    files_dict.setdefault(pos, {'position': pos})[kind] = s
```

although that's even more cryptic than the previous version. ;)

```
files_dict.setdefault(pos, {'position': pos})
```

fetches the sub-dict in `files_dict` with the key `pos`. If it doesn't exist, it's created with an initial key-value pair of `('position', pos)`.

We then update that sub-dict with the `(kind, s)`, where `s` is the full filename of the the current file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use `filename.startswith('bar')` or `filename.startswith('foo')` to distinguish `foo_1.jpg` and `bar_1.jpg`
2. Try to use `position=int(os.path.splitext(filename)[0].split('_')[-1])` instead of `re`.

---

3. Don't use `register = {**foo_register, **bar_register}` :

e.g.

```
a={'foo': '', 'bar': 'uploads/campaigns/1/bar_1.png', 'position': 1}
b={'foo': 'uploads/campaigns/1/foo_.png', 'bar': '', 'position': 1}

print({**a,**b})
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 'uploads/campaigns/1/foo_.png', 'bar': '', 'position': 1}
```

I think this is why you got the unexpected result.

You can try this:

```
a.update({k:v for k,v in b.items() if v})

print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 'uploads/campaigns/1/foo_.png', 'bar': 'uploads/campaigns/1/bar_1.png', 'position': 1}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Try to use `[{}]*9`"? This will cause the list to hold 9 references to the same dict.

Comment: @tobias_k My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, re
cwd = os.getcwd()
print cwd


def update(li, pos, path, key):
    added = False
    if len(li) == 0:
        di=dict()
        di["position"] = int(pos)
        di[key] = path
        li.append(di)
        added = True        
    else:
        for di in li:
            if di["position"]==pos:                
                di[key] = path
                added = True


if not added:
    di=dict()
    di["position"] = int(pos)
    di[key] = path
    li.append(di)    



li = []
for filename in os.listdir(cwd+r'/try'):        # folder name where my files are.
    position = int(re.search('[0-9]+', filename).group())
    print filename, position
    path = cwd + '/' + filename
    if "foo" in filename:        
        update(li, position, path, "foo")
    elif "bar" in filename:
        update(li, position, path, "bar")

print li
```